# ASP.NET Web pages form query validation (razor)

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-webpages

I can't deal at least for some days (I think) with a very typical problem. I'm still a bit newbie that's why I'm asking for help.

I have a SQL Server database, where I have table which is being updated every 4 hours. There is a 50% chance of that some rows or the whole Commission name, won't be there in the next update of that table.

The data I'm getting on my page like below and calling on a master page as helper:

```
@helper drawSummaryTable(String option, String tableType)
{
    var db = Database.Open("CommissionsDB");

    var query = "SELECT * FROM SiempelBizRepTabNew";
    var generateData = db.Query(query);
    query = @"SELECT 
                 COUNT(Commission_Name),
                 SUM(Consumption) as Consumption, 
                 SUM(Obligo) as Obligo, 
                 SUM(ActualCosts) as ActualCosts,
                 SUM(Summary) as Summary
             FROM SiempelBizRepTabNew
             WHERE Commission_Name LIKE @0";

    var ComName = "%" + Request["ComName"] + "%";

    var data = db.Query(query, ComName);

    var grid = new WebGrid(data, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", canPage: false, canSort: false);

 <h1>BestellObligo</h1>

    <form method="post">
        <div id="gridContainer">
            <div id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 150px;">
                Commission name: <input type="text" name="ComName" value="@Request["ComName"]" placeholder="Type here Commission name" />

                <input type="submit" value="Show" />
                <p>Calculated values displayed for: <strong> @Request.Form["ComName"]</strong></p>


                @grid.GetHtml(
          tableStyle: "table",
          alternatingRowStyle: "alternate",
          headerStyle: "header",
          columns: grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("Consumption", "Consumption{Ist Kosten Material}", format: @<text>@item.Consumption.ToString("#,0") €</text>),
                grid.Column("Obligo", "Obligo+ImHaus", format:@<text>@item.Obligo.ToString("#,0") €</text>),
                grid.Column("ActualCosts", "ActualCosts{Ist Fertigung}", format:@<text>@item.AktualNaklady.ToString("#,0") €</text>),
                grid.Column("Summary", "Summary{Gesamt}", format:@<text>@item.Summary.ToString("#,0") €</text>))

)
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

In the second query variable is used where clause for filter (...LIKE @0). When I type in a Commission name that is actually in the table in returns for all elements it's their SUM value. That's good even this solution is not very appropiate.

The problem is when I want to type a Commission name that is no longer in the table the application throws an error "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference"

I know what's the **problem**, I just can't figure out how to solve this. Somehow I need to add a validation of the "data" query "*if there are rows returned than show(count) them, else show a text that the commission name or keywords does not exist anymore*"

Even this can be useful of a mistyped commission name. Thanks for help!

Comment: Thank you, gonna check this out. It is sad to hear that SQL injection screams. Everything in code I got from mikesdotnetting.com and from official webmatrix web development PDFs which is using web pages razor syntax. Maybe will need to gonna find out another ways to create projects like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your query returns any data and then show the data or show a message instead. You can use `Any()` to check if any results were found or `Count()` to return the number of rows if you prefer (check is greater than 0).

```
var data = db.Query(query, ComName);

//if (data.Count() > 0)
if (data.Any())
{
    var grid = new WebGrid(data, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "grid", canPage: false, canSort: false);

    //Rest of your code relating to showing your grid here

}
else
{
    //Show a message here that there was no data
}
```

Comment: well seems like this is actually what I´m looking for. I needed to upgrade my services from razor to MVC with EF, but this can be very helpful. thank you !